# Xamarin Bluetooth LE

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, bluetooth

I'm pretty new with Bluetooth LE, and I'm having some difficulties reading and writing to my device.

I've been following the Monkey.Robotics project to guide me along. I've now reached the part where I've saved the characteristics I need and their corresponding descriptors (for both read and write). I tried implementing the function to write, but I'm having no success.

I've been trying to perform the write using this approach:

```
connectedPeripheral.WriteValue( NSData.FromString (sendText.Text), write_desc);
```

I have also printed out the UUID of all the characteristics I've saved and verified they are correct using my Mac's LightBlue app.

I'm just curious if I need to do any other prep work to be able to perform this write?

I have attached my code to the bottom of this post.

Thanks,

Austin

CODE:

```
partial class ThirdViewController : UIViewController
{
        CBService serviceNeeded;
    private string serv_to_find  = "6e400001-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e";
    private string read_to_find  = "6e400003-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e";
    private string write_to_find = "6e400002-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e";
    CBPeripheral connectedPeripheral;
    CBCharacteristic write;
    CBCharacteristic read;
    CBDescriptor write_desc;

    private string value = "";
    List<CBPeripheral> ps = new List<CBPeripheral> ();

    public ThirdViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

    public ThirdViewController ()
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        MyPickerModel model = new MyPickerModel ();

        // Tie model to selected event
        model.comSelected += (object sender, EventArgs e) => 
        {
            value = model.selectedCom;
        };

        // wire up the DiscoveredPeripheral event to update the table
        BluetoothLEManager.Current.DeviceDiscovered += (object sender, CBDiscoveredPeripheralEventArgs e) => {
            ps = BluetoothLEManager.Current.DiscoveredDevices;

            textBox.Text += "\nFound device: ";
            foreach (var temp in ps)
            {
                model.Add(temp.Name);
                if (value == ""){
                    value = temp.Name;
                }
                textBox.Text += temp.Name + "\n";
            }

            Blue_Picker.Model = model;
        };

        BluetoothLEManager.Current.ScanTimeoutElapsed += (sender, e) => {
            textBox.Text += "\nScan Timeout.";
            BluetoothLEManager.Current.StopScanningForDevices ();
        };
    }

    partial void Logout_Button_TouchUpInside (UIButton sender)
    {
        // Create an instance of our AppDelegate
        var appDelegate = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate as AppDelegate;

        // Get an instance of our MainStoryboard.storyboard
        var mainStoryboard = appDelegate.MainStoryboard;

        // Get an instance of our Login Page View Controller
        var loginPageViewController = appDelegate.GetViewController(mainStoryboard, "LoginPageViewController") as LoginPageViewController;

        // Wire our event handler to show the MainTabBarController after we successfully logged in.
        loginPageViewController.OnLoginSuccess += (s, e) => 
        {
            var tabBarController = appDelegate.GetViewController(mainStoryboard, "MainTabBarController");
            appDelegate.SetRootViewController(tabBarController, true);
        };

        // Set the Login Page as our RootViewController
        appDelegate.SetRootViewController(loginPageViewController, true);
    }

    partial void ScanButton_TouchUpInside (UIButton sender)
    {
        if (BluetoothLEManager.Current.IsScanning)
        {
            BluetoothLEManager.Current.StopScanningForDevices ();
            textBox.Text += "\nDone Scanning";
        }
        else
        {
            BluetoothLEManager.Current.BeginScanningForDevices ();
            textBox.Text += "\nNow Scanning";
        }
    }

    partial void DisconnectButton_TouchUpInside (UIButton sender)
    {
        if (connectedPeripheral == null) {
            textBox.Text += "\nNo device connected.";
            return;
        }

        textBox.Text += "\nDisconnecting from device " + connectedPeripheral.Name + "...";

        BluetoothLEManager.Current.DisconnectPeripheral (connectedPeripheral);
        connectedPeripheral = null;

        Blue_Picker.Hidden = false;
    }

    async partial void ConnectButton_TouchUpInside (UIButton sender)
    {
        if (connectedPeripheral != null) {
            textBox.Text += "\nDevice already connected.";
            return;
        }

        StopScanning ();

        textBox.Text += "\nConnecting to device " + value + "...";

        foreach (var temp in ps){
            if (temp.Name == value){
                BluetoothLEManager.Current.CentralBleManager.ConnectPeripheral (temp, new PeripheralConnectionOptions ());
                await Task.Delay(5000);
                connectedPeripheral = temp;
                InitializePeripheral();
                break;
            }
        }

        Blue_Picker.Hidden = true;
    }

    void StopScanning()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew (() => {
            if (!BluetoothLEManager.Current.IsScanning)
                return;

            BluetoothLEManager.Current.StopScanningForDevices ();
        });
    }

    void InitializePeripheral ()
    {
        // update all our shit

        // > peripheral
        //   > service[s]
        //      > characteristic
        //          > value
        //          > descriptor[s]

        connectedPeripheral.DiscoveredService += HandleDiscoveredService;
        connectedPeripheral.DiscoveredCharacteristic += (sender, e) => {
            HandleDiscoveredCharacteristic((CBPeripheral)sender, serviceNeeded);
        };
        connectedPeripheral.DiscoveredDescriptor += HandleDiscoveredDescriptor;

        connectedPeripheral.DiscoverServices ();
        textBox.Text += "\nLooking for services";
    }

    void HandleDiscoveredService (object sender, NSErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        var peripheral = (CBPeripheral)sender;

        //foreach (CBService service in peripheral.Services) {
        //  textBox.Text += "\nDiscovered Service: " + service.UUID.ToString();
        //  if (!services.Contains (service))
        //      services.Add (service);
        //}

        foreach (CBService service in peripheral.Services) {
            if (service.UUID.ToString().Contains(serv_to_find)) {
                serviceNeeded = service;
            }
        }

        if (serviceNeeded == null)
            return;

        textBox.Text += "\nDiscovered service: " + serviceNeeded.UUID.ToString ();

        // discover the charactersistics
        connectedPeripheral.DiscoverCharacteristics(serviceNeeded);
    }

    void HandleDiscoveredCharacteristic (CBPeripheral peripheral, CBService service)
    {
        foreach (CBService srv in peripheral.Services) {

            // if the service has characteristics yet
            if (srv.Characteristics == null)
                continue;

            foreach (var characteristic in service.Characteristics) {
                if (characteristic.UUID.ToString ().Contains (read_to_find)) {
                    read = characteristic;
                    textBox.Text += "\nDiscovered read characteristic: " + read.UUID.ToString();
                    connectedPeripheral.DiscoverDescriptors (read);
                }
                else if (characteristic.UUID.ToString ().Contains (write_to_find)) {
                    write = characteristic;
                    textBox.Text += "\nDiscovered write characteristic: " + write.UUID.ToString();
                    connectedPeripheral.DiscoverDescriptors (write);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void HandleDiscoveredDescriptor (object sender, CBCharacteristicEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var descriptor in e.Characteristic.Descriptors) {
            if (e.Characteristic.UUID == write.UUID) {
                textBox.Text += "\nWrite descriptor: " + descriptor.ToString ();
                write_desc = descriptor;
            }
            else if (e.Characteristic.UUID == read.UUID) {
                textBox.Text += "\nRead descriptor: " + descriptor.ToString ();
            }
        }
    }

    partial void SendButton_TouchUpInside (UIButton sender)
    {
        textBox.Text += "\nNow writing: " + sendText.Text;
        connectedPeripheral.WriteValue( NSData.FromString (sendText.Text), write_desc);
    }
}
```

I have also tried:

```
connectedPeripheral.WriteValue( NSData.FromString (sendText.Text), write, CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithoutResponse);
```

and that doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 3):

Monkey Robotics is a bit out of date and incomplete. Take a look at [xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le](https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le). It’s basically Monkey Robotics with the gaps filled in. Much easier to work with.